# ASP.NET 2.0 application, TLS 1.2

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, tls1.2

The UPS API is switching over to a mandated TLS 1.2 protocol.  We have asp.net 2.x applications using that API and as of May 31st they're going to stop working.  Actually, they warned us that we would start experiencing outages up until that date which we are currently experiencing.

The app is running on IIS7, Windows 2k8 R2.  I would switch IIS to use TLS 1.2 but we have people consuming our old asp.net 2.x web services and that would cause the same issue for them if we switched over.

Is it possible to set just a single site or pool to use TLS 1.2, but not change it globally?

Our last resort is to write a proxy app in asp.net 4.5.  We'll call this proxy from our 2.x code and then have it call the UPS services.  I was seeing if there was an easier way to avoid writing this code and figuring out a way to do it in server configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to add registry settings on my web service to enable TLS 1.2 (and 1.1).  Leaving the old SSL keys allowed me to support them all and it has not adversely affected my current applications.  However, it has completely solved my issue with the UPS web service.

I used the settings in this article
[Enable TLS on Windows Server and IIS](http://tecadmin.net/enable-tls-on-windows-server-and-iis/)

Comment: What problems with the UPS service did this solve? Can you confirm that your client code is connecting to the UPS via TLS 1.2 (eg. using wireshark or fiddler)? I'm just a little skeptical, because the [security protocols in ASP.NETv3.5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.authentication.sslprotocols%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) don't support TLS v1.2.

Comment: Larry, if at all possible, can you describe precisely how you added registry settings on your web service to enable TLS 1.2?

Comment: I basically followed the instructions in the link above.  I put the two new keys in TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2.  Then in each key I added DWORD values DisabledByDefault (set to 0) and Enabled (set to 1).    However, UPS released another update on Wednesday that is causing this to no longer work.  I think we're going to have to create a service in asp.net 4.5 and then create a proxy class in our 2.x code to that we can access from our legacy application.